# Where could I source the hardware components to create a (commercially viable) embedded Linux / BSD appliance?

Tags: linux, hardware, bsd

I'm looking to pilot an Enterprise Linux / BSD appliance in the field and would like to have a 'few' options when it comes to hardware, I haven't had much luck finding hardware solutions (but I'm guessing I'm not looking in the right place). Any suggestions would be appreciated, are there commercial channels for "appliance oriented" hardware (with relatively low volume requirements)?

Comment: Lots. But you need to be more specific.

Comment: We don't do shopping questions.  Rationale and suggestions for better places for discussion available from http://serverfault.com/questions/292013/good-sites-for-discussing-specific-hosting-provider-server-specification-scenario

Answer (score 2):

Ideas: [Soekris](http://soekris.com); [PC Engines](http://pcengines.ch/alix.htm); [SuperMicro](http://www.supermicro.com/products/embedded/); [Ubiquity RSpro](http://ubnt.com/rspro); [MicroTik](http://www.mikrotik.com/); [Google "Mini ITX"](http://www.google.com/search?q=mini%20itx)